# Uncoment lines using bash script

Tags: bash

```
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner
```

above lines from `/etc/apt/sources.list`.There are number of lines. How to uncomment above 2 lines with bash script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say

```
 sed -e "s/^# deb/deb/g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Instead of

```
 sed -e "s/^# //g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

because th second sed command will either uncomment lines such :

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
```

Comment: No need to use `g` option if you're anchoring to beginning of line -- it can only match once.

Answer (score 2):

The [accepted answer from @m0ntassar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7753263/117259) works, but it will uncomment *all* lines that begin with `# deb` which might open up access to repositories one doesn’t want—or need—access to.

Instead I would recommend targeting lines that are:

1. Lines that begin with `deb` but are commented out with a `#` like this: `# deb`.
2. And lines that *specifically* end with `partner`.

So my suggested Sed command would be as follows:

```
sed -e "/^#.*deb.*partner$/s/^# //g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

That command with the `-e` command would show you the output, but the `-i` flag would edit the file in place:

```
sudo sed -i "/^#.*deb.*partner$/s/^# //g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Running that as `sudo` in this example since editing in place would require `sudo` rights.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/) to replace the #

```
 sed -e "s/^# //g" /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: just want to mathc only once, so you can left the `g` in the sed command. I'm not sure, but my sed accept inplace changes by using an additional `-i` as sed parameter. If you want to save the original file, your should invoke sed like that `sed -i.bak -e '....' FileName`